# Adding single line if statement in string.format

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Can you set a condition inside the string.format parameter.

So if i have

```
string.format("{0}" , if x = 7 then return "SEVEN" else return "ZERO")
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a ternary operator in VB.Net:

```
String.Format("{0}", If(x = 7, "SEVEN", "ZERO"))
```

Same in C# (as Brad already posted):

```
String.Format("{0}", x == 7 ? "SEVEN" : "ZERO")
```

Comment: Your choice. Mark one as the answer and upvote everyone else, so everything should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
C#
String.Format("{0}", x == 7 ? "SEVEN" : "ZERO")
```

In-line [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
VB.NET
String.Format("{0}", IIf(x = 7, "SEVEN", "Zero")) ' Pre-Visual Studio 2008
String.Format("{0}", If(x = 7, "SEVEN", "Zero"))  ' Visual Studio 2008 and forward
```

In-line [ternary method (`IIf()`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (Also, as of VS2008, the short-hand [`If()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is available.)

Comment: _technically_ I was first to answer and have a reference to both `IIf()` & `If()` but the choice is yours. :grin: Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In VB 2008 and higher, the `If` operator is available:

```
If(x = 7, "SEVEN", "ZERO")
```

In VB 2005 and lower, you need to use the `IIf` **function**:

```
IIf(x = 7, "SEVEN", "ZERO")
```

(And if your actual code is what you posted exactly, `String.Format` is entirely superfluous, because it's already a string and you don't need to format it.)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! Use a "tertiary operator" (or actually called a "ternary operator") - like this:

```
string.format("{0}", x == 7 ? "SEVEN" : "ZERO");
```